# GPS external antenna not working

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, antenna, schematics, gps

I am currently working on a GPS module tracking a drone-mounted device. I am using the [ublox CAM-M8Q](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/cam-m8-series) GPS module on a [breakout board](https://shop.watterott.com/CAM-M8Q-Breakout-Multi-GNSS-Module-GPS-QZSS-GLONASS-BeiDou-Galileo).

The internal antenna is working fine, however the signal is rather bad so I'm trying to use the external antenna. I'm using the [hardware integration manual from ublox](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/CAM-M8-FW3_HIM_%28UBX-15030063%29.pdf) for reference for connecting the antenna. This it the [external antenna with LFA](https://de.farnell.com/maxtena/mia1516/antenne-gps-glonass-1-59ghz/dp/2531301) I am using. As pointed out in [this thread](https://portal.u-blox.com/s/question/0D52p00008HKCvmCAH/active-antenna-supply-for-camm8) I connected the supply voltage for the LFA as such:

[image: Sorry for a paint schematic, I'm not able to use EAGLE right now]

However with the antenna connected like this I'm not getting any signal. What did I do wrong and how can I improve this circuit?

Comment: **Use  100  kΩ(typ.)  external  pull  down  resistor  at LNA_ENsignal  whenever  the  signal  is  used externally** have you done this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are you using the U-Blox development board, you'll need to rotate this resistor (bright green highlight):

[image]

This way:

[image]

And connect the active antenna to the "RF_In" U.FL connector.

Comment: Okay, but do I need to keep my circuit with the inductor and the capacitor?

Comment: Yes, of course. You don't want to be feeding DC into the uBlox RF input.

Comment: @OccasionalPoster Sorry, to clarify keep your circuit as-is, only do this change :)

Comment: @Cisco25 I did change it, still no signal

Comment: @OccasionalPoster Strange, did you wait long enough? Sometimes it takes 5-10 minutes for the receiver to acquire satellite signals. Are you using U-blox center to check what the receiver is seeing? In this guide, they recommend to add a 10-Ohm resistor in series with the inductor, measuring the voltage across that resistor could tell you if the antenna LNA is drawing current or not: https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/GLONASS-HW-Design_AppNote_%28GPS.G6-CS-10005%29.pdf#page=12

Comment: @Cisco25 I will try again and wait a bit longer. If that doesnt work I'll add the 10 Ohm resistor. I will let you know if that worked. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Make sure you are by a window or something, GPS does not acquire well in buildings.